# paypal upload cart and default form being open at checkout

Tags: api, paypal, checkout

I can't seem to find an answer to this, even at Paypal. Is it possible to have the Paypal form for entering a credit card be open by default, vs. the login to paypal form be open? Is there a way to code for this using the upload cart method?

Merchant Account Standard

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Website Payments Standard, this is already the default behaviour.
Note however, that - if you've logged on to PayPal previously - the PayPal site will look for your PayPal cookie, and if found, present you with the 'Login to your account' window.
Any new user not previously logged on to PayPal user will be shown the credit card entry screen by default.
Have a look at https://www.x.com/blogs/matt/2011/02/22/how-do-i-make-that-pay-with-credit-card-option-come-up-by-default for a full explanation of this behaviour as well.

You can force this - irrespective of cookie - in Express Checkout by specifying LANDINGPAGE=Billing. No such parameter exists for Website Payments Standard though.